# как получить все book.title в массиве allbooks

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './SearchBooks.css';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class SearchBooks extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            nameBooks: '',
            allBooks: [],
        }
    }
    searchBooks = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            nameBooks: e.target.value
        });
        if (this.state.nameBooks.length > 2) {
           axios.get('http://openlibrary.org/search.json?title=' + this.state.nameBooks)
            .then(res => {
               const titleBooks =  res.data.docs;
               titleBooks.map(book => {
                   this.setState({
                       allBooks: book.title
                   });
                   console.log(this.state.allBooks, 'allbokks')
               });
            });
        };
    };

    async getBooks() {

    }

    render() {
        return (

            <div className='SearchBooks'>
                <div className='title'>
                    <h1>Look for your favorite book </h1>
                </div>
                <div className='search'>
                    <input onChange={this.searchBooks} className='inp' type='text'></input>
                </div>
                <i className="fa fa-search " onClick={() => this.getBooks()} />
            </div>


        )
    }
}
```